# Underline Bottom of Wrapped Text, but Only Width of Text Using CSS Only

Tags: html, css

I have some text that is underlined using border-bottom.  This part is fine, but when the text wraps, the element expands the full width of the parent element creating an underline that exceeds the width of the text.  How can I create a single underline at the bottom of all the text that is only as wide as the wrapped text using *only* CSS (no JS)?

Thank you.

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 325px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper"> 
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do it this way.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .parent {
  background: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 325px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid white; */
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="wrapper"> 
              <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
              <hr style="width:auto", size="3", color=black>  
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but that's not what I'm after.  I want the underline to be just the width of the text.